# React mixing components and html inside root element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, react-component

I want to pass server side data to React components without making async call.
I was wondering about building React app directly from my html page, something like what's written down here.

Is there a way to do something like this inside my html:

```html
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <ReactComponentA description="Lorem ipsum">
      <div>
        Test
      </div>
      ...(maybe other react components or html here)
    </ReactComponentA>
  </div> 
</body>
```

In other words I'm trying to mix html and react components inside react root element in my html view.

I hope I was clear

Thank you very much

Comment: You can't use React components in HTML because they aren't HTML. What is your case?

Comment: I want to pass server side data to react components without making async call

Comment: nesting react components is feasible , sorry did not get what are you trying to achieve here

Comment: Then this is XY problem that should be addressed in another way. Consider updating the question with this information. It's also unclear from pseudocode you posted what kind of data it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components aren't HTML and cannot be used in HTML page. JSX syntax is syntactic sugar for `React.createComponent(...)`. Even though `React.createComponent(...)` could be used in HTML within `<script>`, it wouldn't make much sense there because React components should be rendered with `ReactDOM.render` any way in order to be useful, and this happens inside React application.

Another problem is that if `ReactComponentA` is defined inside React application, it wouldn't be available as `ReactComponentA` in global scope.

If an application is hydrated with data to avoid asynchronous AJAX calls, data can be provided with globals:

```
<script>
window.__APP_DATA__ = {/* provided in server-side template */};
</script>
```

And be used inside an application as `window.__APP_DATA__`.